# How to create a global event?

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, global-variables

I have a global variable g_user as string and a Label lb_welcome to show username, How can i create a global event when g_user changed then will trigger a function

```
Private Sub Login()
    g_user = VerifyUser(id,password)
    lb_welcome.Text = $"Welcome {g_user}"
End Sub
```

I try to do something like this:-

```
   Private Sub RefreshLabel()
        lb_welcome.Text = $"Welcome {g_user}"
   End Sub

   Private Sub g_user_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles g_user.Changed
        RefreshLabel()
   End Sub
```

Above is just an example, lb_welcome.Text contain many global variable, I always have to manually add the function when a variable changed, so is it possible to create a global event to help me run the function automatically?

Comment: There exist no *global variables* in VB .NET. Are you sure your tags are correct? Are you using VB 6?

Comment: @AlexB. Public g_user As String I have this inside a module, and this variable can use in all form, so i thought this is global variable? Im using vb.net not VB6.

Comment: Hm yes public variables in Modules are kind of global...I forgot about those dirty hacks Microsoft provided here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a public Event in your Module which is raised if one of your properties (here g_user) is changed:

```
Public Module MyModule      
    Public Event Changed As EventHandler(Of ChangedEventArgs)

    Private _user As String
    Public Property g_user As String
        Get
            Return _user
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _user = value
            raisePropertyChanged("g_user", value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub raisePropertyChanged(propertyName As String, value As String)
        RaiseEvent Changed(Nothing, New ChangedEventArgs() With {.PropertyName = propertyName, .Value = value})
    End Sub
End Module
```

The EventArgs are pretty straight forward:

```
Public Class ChangedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public PropertyName As String
    Public Value As String
End Class
```

In your form hook the event and react to it:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        AddHandler MyModule.Changed, AddressOf RefreshLabel

    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshLabel(s As Object, e As ChangedEventArgs)
        If e.PropertyName = "g_user" Then
            lb_welcome.Text = $"Welcome {e.Value}"
        Else
            '...
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)