# Close a form opend from a Thread

Tags: vb.net

I'm opening from the main form a second form used to display a "loading gif". at the end of the procesing I want to close that form

```
Dim th As System.Threading.Thread
th = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Task_A)
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA)
th.Start()

Public Sub Task_A()
    Application.Run(frmBusy)
End Sub
```

Tried to close the form using `frmBusy.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() frmBusy.Close()))` but I get an error  `'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created` any idea ?

Comment: I suspect that you're going about things in very much the wrong way. You may benefit from a look at [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567-Modal-Wait-Dialogue-with-BackgroundWorker).

Comment: How do you want this loading form to behave? Should it be modal vs. the main form? I see no benefit in creating a new UI thread just to show a form. Also it seems to behave exactly as if you had done `frmBusy.Show()`. If you have cross-thread issues then you should start it from the existing message loop. If in the form, `Me.Invoke(Sub() frmBusy.Show())` I believe, or substitute Me for MainForm if not running from the form.

Comment: Standard My.Forms misery.  You must use the object reference, not the type name.  This kind of code is very risky, using MTA makes it particularly worse, keep forms on the main thread and do the "processing" on a worker thread.  BackgroundWorker makes it easy.

Comment: *Or* you could send an application-wide event, and add a listener to your form so that it closes itself. Maybe reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42410906/6843158) can help. Here is how to do it: [Global events for your application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28753/Global-events-for-your-application). I doubt you even need a separate thread for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a couple of things going on here.

First, for simplicity's sake, let's assume the form's class name is `frmBusy`, and that is not the name of the instance. If that's the case then what Hans Passant said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547770/close-a-form-opend-from-a-thread#comment107118780_60547770) is very relevant to you.

Also, your question states (I am rearranging words here),

> "I'm opening a second form, from the main form"

I'll take that as you are originating on the main form's UI thread. This means you haven't created a second thread via a BackGroundWorker or explicitly with System.Threading.Thread. Then it's quite simple. Why must you create a new UI thread just to show a loading window? Just use Form.Show()...

```vb
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using myFrmBusy As New frmBusy()
        myFrmBusy.Show()
        Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf longRunningTask)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub longRunningTask()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub
```

Note the classname is `frmBusy` and the instance is `myFrmBusy`. Also, the `Using` block automatically closes and disposes the form when you're done with it. It runs on the main UI thread, as evidenced by the fact that it is shown from a UI (Button.Click) event handler. It also uses `Async / Await` to make the longRunningTask not block the UI.

What if you didn't start from the UI, rather some non-UI thread? I guess this is why you're... making your own UI thread...? Well we can just put it back on the UI thread. In this version, it originates from the longRunningTask, but longRunningTask is a member of the main form, so you can Invoke using `Me`

```vb
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf longRunningTask)
End Sub

Private Sub longRunningTask()
    Using myFrmBusy = Me.Invoke(Function() New frmBusy())
        Me.Invoke(Sub() myFrmBusy.Show())
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Using
End Sub
```

You can also automate the determination whether it's on the correct thread originally or not. This version can be called from the UI or a background thread.

```vb
Private myFrmBusy As frmBusy

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf longRunningTask)
End Sub

Private Sub longRunningTask()
    Try
        myFrmBusyShow()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Finally
        myFrmBusyClose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub myFrmBusyShow()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() myFrmBusyShow())
    Else
        myFrmBusy = New frmBusy()
        myFrmBusy.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub myFrmBusyClose()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() myFrmBusyClose())
    Else
        myFrmBusy?.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

But you may want to ensure this isn't happening twice in succession because the first busy form becomes an orphan and won't get closed automatically.

In any case, it's running on the main UI thread. So if you do want the form to be modal, you can always just do.

```vb
myFrmBusy.ShowDialog()
```

in any of the examples.

There are not many cases when you need to create your own message loop once one has been created in WinForms. I think your simple case does not qualify for one of those cases.